# FileUpload control to System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#

How can set a System.Drawing.Image to the file present in a fileUpload control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the stream from the posted file (on the [`FileContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent.aspx) property of the control) with [`Image.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htxexw02.aspx):

```
var img = Image.FromStream(file.FileContent);
```

Comment: Friggen sweet, exactly what I needed. Thanks Oded.